# Filling UITableView from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    }

    int theRow = indexPath.row;
    if(indexPath.section == 0) theRow += 0;
    if(indexPath.section == 1) theRow += 3;
    if(indexPath.section == 2) theRow += 7;

    CountriesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CountriesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CountriesData *country = (CountriesData *)[appDelegate.countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[cell primaryLabel] setText:country.countryName];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

I am filling `UITableView` from sqlite database. I have 3 sections.

In case of code above each section begins with the first element of the database.
But I need the that each section  filled with elements of datebase in order as variable `theRow` (3 elements, 4 elements, other elements).

Any ideas?

Comment: you compute the value for `theRow`, but grab values from `appDelegate.countries` using `indexPath.row`..

Comment: You mean something like this `CountriesData *country = (CountriesData *)[appDelegate.countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.theRow];
` ?

Comment: CountriesData *country = (CountriesData *)[appDelegate.countries objectAtIndex: theRow]; your problem solved

Comment: @RomanHouse - Should I post my comment as an answer ? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CountriesData *country = (CountriesData *)[appDelegate.countries objectAtIndex: theRow];
```